# GCP Cloud Run "Initializing project for the current region. Resource readiness deadline exceeded."

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

we experience the following behaviour when deploying the [GCP Cloud Run Helloworld Example](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy) for Java. we get the error only for region "europe-west1", it works for "europe-west3". we can't explain why this happens.

```
Creating revision -> Initializing project for the current region. Resource readiness deadline exceeded.
Routing traffic -> Pending
```

it keeps trying and trying and fails in the end. the logs show the following:

```
{
"insertId": "l3d9g6d1ld9",
"logName": "projects/xxx/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access",
"protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "authenticationInfo": {
        "principalEmail": "xxx"
    },
    "authorizationInfo": [
        {
            "granted": true,
            "permission": "run.services.get",
            "resource": "namespaces/xxx/services/basic-helloworld",
            "resourceAttributes": {}
        }
    ],
    "methodName": "google.cloud.run.v1.Services.GetService",
    "request": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.run.v1.GetServiceRequest",
        "name": "namespaces/xxx/services/basic-helloworld"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
        "callerIp": "2003:d2:703:da00:7516:dbd4:276d:e456",
        "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "xxxxxx",
        "destinationAttributes": {},
        "requestAttributes": {
            "auth": {},
            "time": "2021-01-20T07:20:42.152453Z"
        }
    },
    "resourceLocation": {
        "currentLocations": [
            "europe-west1"
        ]
    },
    "resourceName": "namespaces/xxx/services/basic-helloworld",
    "serviceName": "run.googleapis.com",
    "status": {
        "code": 5,
        "message": "Resource 'basic-helloworld' of kind 'SERVICE' in region 'europe-west1' in project 'xxx' does not exist."
    }
},
"receiveTimestamp": "2021-01-20T07:20:42.907042515Z",
"resource": {
    "labels": {
        "configuration_name": "",
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "project_id": "xxx",
        "revision_name": "",
        "service_name": "basic-helloworld"
    },
    "type": "cloud_run_revision"
},
"severity": "ERROR",
"timestamp": "2021-01-20T07:20:42.097208Z"
}
```

we are currently stuck. any help highly appreciated.

cheers
marcel

Comment: Do you request special things when you deploy? Memory, cpu, min-instance,... Do you have special parameters?

Comment: Since you are experiencing this while deploying the hello world example this could be an issue with that specific region of Cloud Run, I would recommend you open a Bug Report in [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=608076&template=0), so Google can check if that is the case.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere no, nothing special. just the tutorial ...

Comment: @RafaelLemos will do that. thanks.